# Como Atualizar os dados a partir de uma diretiva vue 2?

Tags: vue.js

Como posso realizar o seguinte procedimento para atualizar os dados a partir de uma diretiva no vue.

```js
var select = Vue.directive('select', {
 twoWay: true,
 bind: function(el, binding, vnode){
  
    // Como acessar op ?????
   // this.set()
  }
})

new Vue({
 el: '#demo',
    data: function(){
   return {
     op: 2
    }
  }
});
```

```css
select{
  width:200px;
  padding:5px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <p>Opção: {{ op }}</p>
  <select v-select>
    <option v-bind:value="1">1</option>
    <option v-bind:value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @JJay não consegui entender muito bem o objetivo dessa sua implementação. O que você deseja alcançar? Por que não usar um v-model para atualizar os dados?

Comment: Estou utilizando Materialize em um projeto, e alguns recursos utilizam o jQuery, neste caso, no campo select utilizaria o método .change() do jQuery para interceptar e então atualizar o valor do model e fazer valer no escopo do Vue.

Answer (score -1):

[A propriedade TwoWay foi removida na versão 2 do Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#twoWay-Prop-Option-removed). A melhor maneira de fazer o que deseja é simplesmente usar a diretiva nativa do Vue.js criada para isso o **v-model**. Com ele poderá atualizar um conteúdo a partir do valor do select.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: function() {
    return {
      op: 2
    }
  }
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <p>Opção: {{ op }}</p>
  <select v-model='op'>
    <option v-bind:value="1">1</option>
    <option v-bind:value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Dessa maneira funciona. Entretanto, no Materialize o campo select é escondido e uma lista estilizada simula suas ações, sendo assim, o controle de tais ações são realizadas pelo jQuery a fim de propaga-las para o respectivo campo select.